# $\lim_{x\to \infty} \ln x=\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I'm reading the following reasoning:

> Since $\underset{n\to \infty}{\lim}\ln 2^n=\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}n\cdot(\ln 2)=\infty$ then necessarily $\underset{x\to \infty}{\lim}\ln x =\infty$.

I don't understand how the generalisation was done from $\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln 2^n=\infty$ to $\lim_{x\to \infty} \ln x=\infty$.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\log x = \infty$ we need to show that for every $M > 0$ there is an $N > 0$ such that $\log x > M$ for all $x > M$. And you already know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\log 2^{n} = \infty$ so that given any $M_{1} > 0$ there is a positive integer $m$ such that $\log 2^{n} > M_{1}$ for all $n \geq m$.

Let's see how we can achieve our goal from the given information. First idea is to take $M_{1} = M$ so that there is an integer $m > 0$ such that $\log 2^{n} > M$ for all $n \geq m$. Now we know that if $x > 2^{n} \geq 2^{m}$ then $\log x > \log 2^{n} > M$ and thus it is sufficient to take $N = 2^{m}$ and you are done.

The fundamental idea is that $\log x$ is monotone (we don't need strictly monotone nature in the above proof) and hence in order to prove that $\log x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ it is sufficient to consider a sequence $s_{n}$ of positive numbers such that $s_{n} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and show that $\log s_{n} \to \infty$. Here we have taken $s_{n} = 2^{n}$ and we could have taken $s_{n} = a^{n}$ with any $a > 1$. The reason we take $s_{n}$ of the form $a^{n}$ is that we have the property $\log a^{n} = n\log a$ and this makes it easy to show that $\log s_{n} \to \infty$. If we take any other sequence say $s_{n} = 2n$ then we get $\log 2n = \log 2 + \log n$ then we need to establish that $\log n$ tends to infinity and this is back to the problem with which we started.

Answer (score 4):

The logarithm is monotone, so it is enough to look at what happens at the integers. Or even the integers of the form $2^n$.

More concretely, given $K>0$, there exists $n_0$ with $\ln 2^{n_0}\geq K$. Then, if $x\geq 2^{n_0}$, we have 
$$
\ln x\geq\ln 2^{n_0}\geq K. 
$$
So $\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln x=\infty$.

Comment: The restriction to the integers is possible because the logarithm is **strictly** monotone and not only monotone, otherwise two successive integers can have the same logarithm and the restriction would not work, Is what I said correct ?

Comment: It is strictly monotone indeed, I think that's what Martin kind of assumed when you look at the basic definition of the $ln$ being introduced as an integral

Comment: I know it is strictly monotone but  I'm asking if the argument of Martin works because the logarithm is strictly monotone and it would not work if we had only monotone function

Comment: Assuming that the function does not stay constant for integers forever (then it wouldn't be monotone anymore) Martin's argument should also work if for two consecutive integers the y-value is the same

Comment: Also I don't see anything special about the choice of the integers $2^n$ that makes it essential to compute the limit of  the logarithm function

Comment: $f$ is monotone if $x<y $ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$ but $f$ is strictly monotone means $x<y$ implies $f(x)<f(y)$. So a constant map is monotone in this manner.

Comment: The choice of base $2$ is arbitrarily chosen in the sense you could also pick $3$

Comment: Is taking to the power also arbitrary ? I mean he could take $2n$ instead of $2^n$, I mean any sequence of integers that converges to infinity ? or maybe any sequence of real numbers converging to infinity not only a sequence of integers ?

Comment: If you take $2n$, you gain little because $\ln2n=\ln2+\ln n$, and no advantage is gained. In the case of $2^n$, the logarithm takes the $2$ out so you only need to know that $\ln 2>0$. The argument works with any other number other $r$ other than $2$, provided that $r>1$ (so that $\ln r>0$).

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that we can make $\ln x$ arbitrarily large by making $x$ sufficiently large. Hence, say we want to make $\ln x > c$ for arbitrarily large $c$. Then for some $n>\frac{c}{\ln 2}$ take

$x>2^n$ so that $\ln x > n \ln 2 > c$ noting that $\ln$ is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

For $x,y > 0$, $\ln x > \ln y$ if and only if $x > y$.  Also, for any $n$ you can find an $x$ for which $x > 2^n$.

This shows for any $S > 0$ there exists an $x_0$ such that $\ln x > S$ for all $x > x_0$.  That is what it means for $\ln x$ to have limit $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

For $2\leq n\in N$ and  $x\geq n$ we have $$\ln x=\int_1^x(1/y)\;dy\geq \int_1^n(1/y)\;dy=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\int_j^{j+1}(1/y)\;dy\geq \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\int_j^{j+1}(1/(j+1))\;dy=$$ $$=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}1/(j+1).$$ There are many ways to show that this last sum has no upper bound as $n\to \infty.$ The simplest, I think,is $$1/2+1/3+1/4\;>\;1/2+2(1/4)=1,$$  $$1/2+1/3+...1/8\;>\;1/2+2(1/4)+4(1/8)=3/2,$$  $$1/2+1/3+...+1/16\;>\;1/2+2(1/4)+4(1/8)+8(1/16)=2,$$...... et cetera.